# How to fix this python portaudio binding issue?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I was writing a code for speech to text in python but got stucked up facing this issue "Please build and install the PortAudio Python bindings first."

```
import speech_recognition  as sr;
r=sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("say something");
audio=r.listen(source)
try:
    print(r.recognize_google(audio));
except:
    pass;
```

Comment: So you need to build and install portaudio python bindings first, what you do not understand exactly? You can run 'pip install pyaudio'

Comment: @Nikolay Shmyrev Actually i installed pyaudio from the external source because as i was running 'pip install pyaudio' and  got an error saying that u have to install Microsoft visual c++ 14.0 so i installed it but still got error while installing pyaudio so i chose to install it from external source directly.

Comment: That was a wrong choice

Answer (score 0):

First, the code is not correct:

```
import speech_recognition  as sr
r = sr.Recognizer()
with sr.Microphone() as source:
    print("say something")
    audio = r.listen(source)
text = r.recognize_google(audio)
try:
   print("You said: {}",format(text))

except:
   print("Sorry I couldn't understand you")
```

Next, you need to install pyaudio, speech_recognition and 
portaudio. Note you can't install these with pip due to the
fact that they are not part of the c:libary.

I suggest you download these online.